# Echo values of array

Tags: php

I have an array, which if i do a var_dump() looks like this:

```
array(5) { ["id"]=>  string(10) "2147483647" ["date"]=>  string(10) "1304773322" ["twitteruser"]=>  string(9) "Username" ["twitterurl"]=>  string(103) "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1070129036/30175_415127663488_509603488_44556621_2331814_n_normal.jpg" ["govequote"]=>  string(80) "text" }
```

How can I echo each one selectivly, E.g

I want $image to equal `["twitterurl"]=>  string(103) "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1070129036/30175_415127663488_509603488_44556621_2331814_n_normal.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)?

```
foreach($someArray as $key => $element)
{
    echo '["'.$key . '"] => ';
    var_dump($element);
}
```

On array like:

```
$someArray = array('a' => 'b');
```

Returns:

```
["a"] => string(1) "b"
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gDceQu)

Answer (score 1):

whatever the name of your array that you are dumping 
do this

```
$image = $arrayName['twitterurl'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = trim( $arr[ "twitterurl" ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data in the array one of two ways:

```
$image = $arrayVariable["twitterurl"];
```

or

```
foreach($arrayVariable as $key => $value){
  if($key === "twitterurl")
  $image = $value;
}
```